# MySQL throws syntax error when syntax is correct

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code which should retrieve 10 records at once from my database table:

```
$query = 'SELECT *
          FROM shares
          ORDER BY create_date DESC
          LIMIT :sharesPerPage OFFSET :lowerBound';
$this->prepare($query);
$this->bind(':sharesPerPage', $sharesPerPage);
$this->bind(':lowerBound', $lowerBound);
$this->execute();
```

For some reason a PDO Exception is being thrown with information that I have wrong syntax around '10' OFFSET '0', which corresponds to `$sharesPerPage` and `$lowerBound` respectively.

I have checked everything already, but the query still evaluates to an error. What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to cast your value into int. Otherwise it will converted as string

```
$this->bind(':sharesPerPage', (int)$sharesPerPage, PDO::PARAM_INT));
$this->bind(':lowerBound', (int)$lowerBound, PDO::PARAM_INT));
```